# JqGrid most efficient way to add rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have an application written in JQuery where I use JqGrid along with Ajax JSON calls to call stored procedures in a database with VB as my code-behind language.
This works all fine, up until I get 2k results+.
When I get more than 2-3k results back, the program crashes.
I read somewhere that `grd_Order.jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, data.d[i]);`
is a inefficient way to add data to my grid. What other possibilities do I have?

My code looks somewhat like this:

```
grd_Order.jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: order_Data,
                colNames: ['OrdNo', 'IdCust', 'CustName', 'CustAdd', 'CustZip', 'CustPhone', 'InvNo', 'InvDate', 'VehRef', 'VehReg', 'Prefix', 'WOSeries', 'PayType', 'OrderType', 'Status', 'OrderStatus'],
                colModel: [{ name: 'ORDNO', index: 'ORDNO', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 75 },
                            { name: 'IDCUSTOMER', index: 'IDCUSTOMER', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 65 },
                            { name: 'CUSTOMER', index: 'CUSTOMER', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 150 },
                            { name: 'CUSTADD1', index: 'CUSTADD1', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 100 },
                            { name: 'CUSTZIP', index: 'CUSTZIP', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 50 },
                            { name: 'CUSTPHONEMOBILE', index: 'CUSTPHONEMOBILE', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 75 },
                            { name: 'InvNo', index: 'InvNo', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 75 },
                            { name: 'InvDate', index: 'InvDate', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 80 },
                            { name: 'REFNO', index: 'REFNO', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 80 },
                            { name: 'REGNO', index: 'REGNO', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 80 },
                            { name: 'PREFIX', index: 'PREFIX',  sorttype: "string",hidden:true },
                            { name: 'WOSeries', index: 'WOSeries',  sorttype: "string", hidden: true },
                            { name: 'PayType', index: 'PayType', sorttype: "string", hidden: true },
                            { name: 'OrderType', index: 'OrderType', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 60 },
                            { name: 'STATUS', index: 'STATUS', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 60 },
                            { name: 'OrderStatus', index: 'OrderStatus', sorttype: "string", classes: 'wosearchpointer', width: 60 }
                            ],
                pager: jQuery('#pagerOrd'),
                hidegrid: false,
                rowNum: pageSize,//can fetch from webconfig
                rowList: 5,
                viewrecords: true,
                height: 350,
                async: false, //Very important,
                subGrid: false,
                autoWidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                sortname: 'ORDNO'
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "frmWOSearchPopup.aspx/Order_Search",
                data: "{q: '" + s + "', 'isBargain': '" + isBargain + "', 'isOrder': '" + isOrder +"', 'isCreditnote': '" + isCreditnote + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,//Very important
                success: function (data) {
                    for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++)
                    {                         
                        grd_Order.jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, data.d[i]);
                    }
                    jQuery("#grdOrder").setGridParam({ rowNum: pageSize }).trigger("reloadGrid");
                }
            });               
        }
```

As you can see, this for loop can loop thousands of times. Is this a good way of doing things? How can I do i better/more efficient?

Comment: Which value have `pageSize`? `rowList: 5` is wrong. The value should be the list of values like `rowList: [5, 10, 20, 100]`. You wrote about "2-3k results". Do you mean 2-3K of data or 2-3K of rows? What is `order_Data`? Do you want **concatenate** the data from the server with the data from `order_Data`? In any way it would be better that *jqGrid make* Ajax request for you and fill the grid with the data. Could you include an example of data returned from the server (1-2 rows or data) and the same from `order_Data` array. Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid?

Comment: Contains the items of data an native unique id? I mean: is, for example, `ORDNO` value different in every item of data?

Comment: Pagesize is 50. What happens if rowlist is 5? This works fine?? 2-3k rows I meant. Orderdata is just data...just an empty var, I dont need to call it that

Comment: Could you post **an example** with 2-3 rows of test data, which will b returned from the server and 1-2 row of `order_Data`? Do you need to display both `order_Data` and the data return from the server **together**? You don't answered on other questions, which I asked previously: the **version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), the **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) , which column or property can be used as unique rowid?